# C program for Armstrong Number not outputting correctly

Tags: c

What's wrong with this program. It compiles but is not giving correct output.

```
/* Program for Armstrong Number*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void main()
{
        int num,sum=0,temp,d;
        printf("\n========Program for Armstrong Number=========\n");
        printf("Enter the number        :       ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        temp=num;
        while(temp>10){
                d=temp%10;
                sum+=pow(d,3);
                d/=10;
        }
        sum+=pow(temp,3);

        if(sum==num)
                printf("\nThe number %d is an Armstrong Number\n",num);
        else
                printf("\nThe number %d is not an armstrong number\n",num);
}
```

Comment: The `while` loop is apparently infinite. The condition `temp>10` won't change since you don't modify the `temp` variable inside the loop. That's one problem I see.

Comment: What output do you *expect* for a given input, and what output do you *get* for that input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   while(temp>10){
            d=temp%10;
            sum+=pow(d,3);
            d/=10;             // this should be temp/=10;
       }
```

This loop is infinite as you don't modify  `temp` .

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash  Did it solved problem  ? I hardly think so >

Comment: No, I had to make a few changes.

Answer (score 0):

Change `d/=10;`  to `temp/=10;`

Check the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

 int main()
{
    int num,sum=0,temp,d;
    printf("\n========Program for Armstrong Number=========\n");
    printf("Enter the number        :       ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    temp=num;
    while(temp>10){
            d=temp%10;
            sum+=pow(d,3);
            temp/=10;
    }
    sum+=pow(temp,3);

    if(sum==num)
            printf("\nThe number %d is an Armstrong Number\n",num);
    else
            printf("\nThe number %d is not an armstrong number\n",num);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the error in the `while` loop already pointed out, your program is summing the cubes of the digits. An Armstrong number is a *n* digit number that is equal to the sum of the *nth* powers of its individual digits. The following is from Wikipedia:

> In recreational number theory, a narcissistic number (also known as a pluperfect digital invariant (PPDI), an Armstrong number (after Michael F. Armstrong) or a plus perfect number) is a number that is the sum of its own digits each raised to the power of the number of digits.

So if you want to test for what I understand to be an Armstrong number, you first need to count the digits to know what power to raise the digits to. Here is your code modified to accomplish this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void main()
{
  int num, sum = 0, temp, d;
  int digits = 0; // Added variable to count digits
  printf("\n========Program for Armstrong Number=========\n");
  printf("Enter the number        :       ");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  // Count the number of digits
  temp = num;
  while (temp != 0){
    digits++;
    temp = temp / 10;
  }

  temp = num;
  while (temp != 0){
    d = temp % 10;
    sum += pow(d, digits);
    temp /= 10; // This was d /= 10;
  }

  if (sum == num)
    printf("\nThe number %d is an Armstrong Number\n", num);
  else
    printf("\nThe number %d is not an armstrong number\n", num);
}
```

If you just want to test if the number is equal to the sum of the cubes of the individual digits, then just fix the `while` loop.